# Three radio button in android but last one not visible in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/re1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioSex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="455dp" >

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/alphaa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alphabetical(A-Z)"
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/alphaz"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alphabetical(Z-A)" />
            <RadioButton
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Distance" />

        </RadioGroup>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

The radio button last not visible when run code.
   Three radio button in xml.when the run code last only not visible.the two button perfectly working.Any idea.

In xml code showing three button when i am running the code it does not showing.

Comment: change the height of parent layout to

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: provide screenshot for this issue.

Comment: if your radio button are vertically aligned then have a look at the height of the relative layout which may not be sufficient to display you the third radiobutton

Comment: Thanks for all help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as below : Please, Check.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/re1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/alphaa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Alphabetical(A-Z)" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/alphaz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Alphabetical(Z-A)" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/diswtance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Distance" />

    </RadioGroup>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Change Main Layout's height bro...You should not use the fix dp for the height in your root layout. You can either use wrap_content or match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Change `RelativeLayout` Layout Height.

**`wrap_content`**

Setting a View's size to wrap_content will force it to expand only far enough to contain the values (or child controls) it contains.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/re1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


Your Radio group

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set  android:layout_height="wrap_content"

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/re1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
       <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioSex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


         .
         .
         .
        </RadioGroup>
     </RelativeLayout>
```